# R: arules packages eclat() error "error in eclat not enough memory".

Tags: r, arules

I am using Rstudio server (R 3.2.3). Using eclat() with 5x,xxx transactions each of them has 35 items. I got the 'not enough memory' error below. However when I checked on RAM, there were still lot of free memory left. I have tried increasing --max-ppsize and expression to 500,000 but it still did not work.[image]

How should I fix this error?

Comment: i had the same problem with a 1k x 11.5k data matrix. i was not impressed with the package and settled for this http://www.philippe-fournier-viger.com/spmf/ this might be more fiddly than using an R package but at least it worked.

Comment: Two suggestions.  Try using `apriori` instead of `eclat`, and I would consider reducing the maxlen from 10 (which would result in enormous combinations).  I am able to use that configuration on much larger data sets than the one that you are using.